# Remotely Enable USB Debugging on my Samsung S8+ when the screen is dead

Tags: usb, usb-debugging, usb-connection-mode, broken-screen

My Samsung S8+ recently had its screen die. I am trying to use Vysor to mirror the screen onto my laptop, but I cannot turn on USB Debugging due to the dead screen.

Is there a way to remotely enable USB Debugging? Or is there a way to bypass the requirement altogether?

Comment: The S8 may be old enough to support an external screen connected via MHL adapter so that you can connect to to an external monitor or TV. Alternatively Android phones can be controlled via USB mouse or keyboard. If you manage to add blindly an Bluetooth keyboard you can acknowledge the adb dialog that pops up when you try to use adb from a connected PC.